# AnimationDrawables in bindView for custom ListView Adapters

Tags: android, listview, animation, android-widget, imageview

I have a custom `ListActivity` that uses a `SimpleCursorAdapter` subclass. In my `newView()` and `bindView()` methods, I am trying to dynamically create an `AnimationDrawable`, depending on database data. The ImageViews only display the first drawable, and do not animate.

```
@Override
public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {
    Resources res = context.getResources();

    Drawable frame1 = null;
    if(tt.getDrawable() != null) frame1 = res.getDrawable(tt.getDrawable());

    ImageView icon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.idt_icon);

    AnimationDrawable transition = new AnimationDrawable();
    transition.addFrame(frame1, 500);
    transition.addFrame(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.sunny_thought), 1000);
    transition.start();
    icon.setImageDrawable(transition);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
frameAnimation.setOneShot(false);
```

sometimes it should be `frameAnimation.stop();` and then `frameAnimation.start();`